# Python RE search method pyschools T12 Q10

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm struggling with getting the correct answer on the exercise, when i input this on the pyshcools website it gives out an error as it states:
File "", line 1, in
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Iv'e run my script on a separate program called geany and show's the expected answer there may be something that i'm not seeing, any help is appreciated. Below is the problem with my script:

```
>>> re.search(regex1, 'a1b22c333d4444').groups()
('22', '333')
>>> re.search(regex2, 'a1b22c333d4444').groups()
('c', 'd')
```

Complete the RE below to match the output of the above examples.
The RE should be as generic as possible.

```
import re

regex1 = r"([\d]{2})[^2]([3]{3})"     
regex2 = r"(c)\d{3}(d)"


print(re.search(regex1, 'a1b22c333d4444').groups())
print(re.search(regex2, 'a1b22c333d4444').groups())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: it needs to output what is shown at the beginning of the exercise: in regex1 outputs (22,333) and regex2 (c,d)

Comment: But the code gives that result https://ideone.com/u1oOO3 What do you mean by `as generic as possible`?

Comment: The problem does not go in to detail when stating as generic as possible. I'm guessing as simple as possible. When i input this on the pyscools website it gives out an error

Comment: I think this question is a bit unclear to answer, the critera are very broad.